# How to create a "template" of records in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, templates, model

Users can create surveys. Survey's have questions and questions have answer options (ie. a multiple choice question).

What I want to do is create survey templates...so users can, with the click of a button, create a new survey with pre-set questions and answer options.

We've already got a functioning app, so that's not the question. And we've already got the ability to duplicate/copy/clone surveys as well. Also not the question.

The question is, how do I create a bunch of predefined surveys/questions/answer options that any user of the app has access to?

Do I store all the settings as a hash in some sort of `templates` table (and then just run `Survey.create({:questions => {:answers =>{}})`? Or some other method that I'm just not thinking of?

Does that make sense? Any more clarification needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you add a flag (boolean) called `is_template` to the survey model? Then you can just create a normal survey and set the `is_template` flag high. Users can then see all surveys with this flag set and copy them.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Single Table Inheritance for the Survey model, to distinguish between Surveys and SurveyTemplates.
This way you can also better integrate Authorization.

When using STI in Rails, the model needs a :type attribute, and Rails stores the class name in that attribute for each record.

See:

http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/single-table-inheritance-in-rails.html